# Android Deep Link with a URI that contains no paths but data-only

Tags: android, uri, deep-linking

I want to add support for a deep link of a URI with the following scheme:

```
xrb:xrb_3wm37qz19zhei7nzscjcopbrbnnachs4p1gnwo5oroi3qonw6inwgoeuufdp?amount=10000
```

The `amount` parameter is optional, the second part is a required address. So essentially the schema is `xrb:` the first part `xrb_3wm37qz19zhei7nzscjcopbrbnnachs4p1gnwo5oroi3qonw6inwgoeuufdp` is any string and `amount` is an optional parameter.

Looking at the Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#java), what I'm not clear about is how to retrieve the data from my activity, particularly for the part that doesn't come in as a parameter (`xrb_3wm37qz19zhei7nzscjcopbrbnnachs4p1gnwo5oroi3qonw6inwgoeuufdp`)

The URI is a standard that other applications and services use so I'd rather not change it or do anything proprietary, but is it possible to have a deep link with a URI of this format?

Basically all I'm looking for is when clicking a link containing the URI, the app will open and pre-load some data for them based on the URI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accomplished by creating an `intent-filter` in AndroidManifest

```
<!-- xrb uri scheme -->
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="xrb" />
</intent-filter>
```

And retrieving the URI in the activity's `onCreate`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
if (data != null) {
    Timber.d("inuri %s", data.toString());
} else {
    Timber.d("inuri null");
}
```